# Address bar Spoofing

Tags: web-browser

The exploit explained by security researcher Rafay Baloch that using characters like **'|'** or unicode characters like **U+FE70**, **U+0622**, **U+0623** could lead to reversing of the `site url` and leads to various types of web attacks. I tried on Firefox 49 on which it does not work. Is the browser already patched?

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in the Firefox 48 release, there is a security advisory on the Mozilla foundation's website. It seems that it only affects the Android version of the browser, so not only are you using a release that has been properly patched, but if you're using a desktop browser you would not have witnessed the vulnerability otherwise.

> Security researcher Rafay Baloch reported a mechanism to spoof the addressbar in Firefox for Android using right-to-left character sets when combined with left-to-right characters. This can be used to cause only certain portions of the loaded left-to-right character portion of the URL to be displayed, misleading users as to what site is loaded, possibly leading to phishing attacks.
>
> This vulnerability does not affect the desktop version of Firefox.

[Link to source](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2016-82/)